# CSS Transition Hover Button For Nav

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, css-transitions

I am trying to add a transition delay for my drop down nav. I want it to lag for about 2 seconds so it doesn't disappear too quickly. I have tried putting

```
transition: 2s ease;
```

with the class `.dropdown-content`

```
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 20em;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition: 2s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

but it has no affect.

To sum it up, here are all the HTML and CSS that I am using:

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: @color1;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    transition: 2s ease;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 20em;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 2s ease;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: @darkColor;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: @color2;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">=</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#food_menu">Menu</a>
            <a href="#map">Map</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add your css in <style></style> tag.

Comment: please provide a fiddle or codepan

Comment: here is the link for the fiddle, sorry I am very new to this and still learning https://jsfiddle.net/emily_m_re/tdfpzya1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
     $('.dropdown-content').fadeIn(0);
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-content').fadeOut(2000);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: @color1;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 20em;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: @darkColor;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
/*  display: inline-block; */
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: @color2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">=</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#food_menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="#map">Map</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

You could also change the time of fadein & fadeout from jquery code. I have changed it to 0ms for fadeIn and 2000ms for fadeOut.
Their default value is 400ms.

Answer (score 0):

just "transition" doesnt work for all browsers.

target all browsers by using

```
-webkit-transition: 2s ease;
-moz-transition: 2s ease;
-ms-transition: 2s ease;
-o-transition: 2s ease;
transition: 2s ease;
```